# Using Python, How can I evaluate an expression in the form of prefix notation compacted?

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I am currently working on the python problemsets on a website called singpath. The question is:

Prefix Evaluation
Create a function that evaluates the arithmetic expression in the form of prefix notation without spaces or syntax errors. The expression is given as a string, all the numbers in the expression are integer 0~9, and the operators are +(addition), -(subtraction), *(multiplication), /(division), %(modulo), which operate just the same as those in Python.
Prefix notation, also known as Polish notation, is a form of notation for logic, arithmetic, and algebra. it places operators to the left of their operands. If the arity of the operators is fixed, the result is a syntax lacking parentheses or other brackets that can still be parsed without ambiguity.

---

This seems simple enough but the string is condensed with no spaces in the input to splice out the data. How could I separate the data from the string without importing modules? Furthermore how could I use the results of the data to solve the given equation? Also please keep in minf that Singpath solutions must be in **ONE** function that cannot use methods that couldn't be found in the standard python library. This also includes functions declared within the solution :S

Examples:

```
>>> eval_prefix("+34")
7
>>> eval_prefix("*−567")
-7
>>> eval_prefix("-*33+2+11")
5
>>> eval_prefix("-+5*+1243")
14
>>> eval_prefix("*+35-72")
40
>>> eval_prefix("%3/52")
1
```

See my point no spaces D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, not as snazzy as alex jordan's lamba/reduce solution, but it doesn't choke on garbage input.  It's sort of a recursive descent parser meets bubble sort abomination (I'm thinking it could be a little more efficient when it finds a solvable portion than just jumping back to the start. ;)

```
import operator
def eval_prefix(expr):
    d = {'+': operator.add,
         '-': operator.sub,
         '*': operator.mul,
         '/': operator.div, # for 3.x change this to operator.truediv
         '%': operator.mod}
    for n in range(10):
        d[str(n)] = n
    e = list(d.get(e, None) for e in expr)
    i = 0
    while i + 3 <= len(e):
        o, l, r = e[i:i+3]
        if type(o) == type(operator.add) and type(l) == type(r) == type(0):
            e[i:i+3] = [o(l, r)]
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
    if len(e) != 1:
        print 'Error in expression:', expr
        return 0
    else:
        return e[0]

def test(s, v):
    r = eval_prefix(s)
    print s, '==', v, r, r == v

test("+34", 7)
test("*-567", -7)
test("-*33+2+11", 5)
test("-+5*+1243", 14)
test("*+35-72", 40)
test("%3/52", 1)
test("****", 0)
test("-5bob", 10)
```

Comment: Thankyou John! Your code is much easier for me to understand then the lambda expression (I'm still a beginner don't cha know). Looking back I should have looked for an operator module in the python library! Because I am silly (and tend to overlook things) my getting main problem was filling my lists. I didn't use the range() method and instead was trying to directly change the string into a list.. without verifying the type in the list. If (when) I get enough reputation I'll definitly upvote your solution! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I think the crucial bit here is "all the numbers in the expression are integer 0~9". All numbers are single digit. You don't need spaces to find out where one number ends and the next one starts. You can access the numbers directly by their string index, as lckknght said.

To convert the characters in the string into integers for calculation, use ord(ch) - 48 (because "0" has the ASCII code 48). So, to get the number stored in position 5 of input, use ord(input[5]) - 48.

To evaluate nested expressions, you can call your function recursively. The crucial assumption here is that there are always exactly two operants to an operator.

Comment: When I was typing up the answer I thought about using ascii values but decided not to try it as I wanted to look at the problem with fresh eyes :P Thankyou for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2):

Your "one function" limitation isn't as bad as you think. Python allows defining functions inside functions. In the end, a function definition is nothing more than assigning the function to a (usually new) variable. In this case, I think you will want to use recursion. While that can also be done without an extra function, you may find it easier to define an extra recursion function for it. This is no problem for your limits:

```
def eval_prefix (data):
    def handle_operator (operator, rest):
        # You fill this in.
    # and this, too.
```

That should be enough of a hint (if you want to use a recursive approach).

Comment: Same as Sean :P I'm not great with recursion so I should look up a tutorial/breakdown of it :P Thanks for the hint though! If I didn't get a detailed answer above then I would have scoured the internet for recursion which would have led me in the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: I never knew you could create a function in a function I thought that was a huge don't. :P Thanks for that tip, it should be put to good use in the future! EDIT: My previous comment wasn't there when I typed this... I like this one better... thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Well, one-liner fits in? Reduce in python3 is hidden in functools
Somewhat lispy :)

```
eval_prefix = lambda inp:\
            reduce(lambda stack, symbol:\
            (
              (stack+[symbol]) if symbol.isdigit() \
             else \
              (
                stack[:-2]+\
                [str(
                      eval(
                           stack[-1]+symbol+stack[-2]
                          )
                    )
                ]
              )
            ), inp[::-1], [])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the complex code... Only problem... I'm a beginner in programming.... I'm not much of a Pythonista yet :P So... feel free to expand it a little if you want to truly help XD

Answer (score 0):

The hint that you are most likely looking for is "strings are iterable":

```
def eval_prefix(data):
    # setup state machine
    for symbol_ in data:
        # update state machine
```

Comment: Thanks Sean but I had that much down.... the problem was conversion from string to list and proper recursion... I'm new to these things :P Thanks though XD

Answer (score 0):

Separating the elements of the string is easy. All elements are a single character long, so you can directly iterate over (or index) the string to get at each one. Or if you want to be able to manipulate the values, you could passing the string to the `list` constructor.

Here are some examples of how this can work:

```
string = "*-567"

# iterating over each character, one at a time:
for character in string:
    print(character) # prints one character from the string per line

# accessing a specific character by index:
third_char = string[2] # note indexing is zero-based, so 3rd char is at index 2

# transform string to list
list_of_characters = list(string) # will be ["*", "-", "5", "6", "7"]
```

As for how to solve the equation, I think there are two approaches.

One is to make your function recursive, so that each call evaluates a single operation or literal value. This is a little tricky, since you're only supposed to use one function (it would be much easier if you could have a recursive helper function that gets called with a different API than the main non-recursive function).

The other approach is to build up a stack of values and operations that you're waiting to evaluate while taking just a single iteration over the input string. This is probably easier given the one-function limit.

Comment: Ahh... stupid computer just stole my comment :P So the breakdown: Thankyou so much for the definition of recursion (and suggestion), An easy to read string -> list conversion and most of all your time. Thanks again!